# What does the "All Cases" dashlet actually display?

Tags: civicase, dashboard, dashlet

Does anyone know what the criteria are for a case to be displayed when using the "All Cases' dashlet?

What seems to be clear is that what it doesn't display is all of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right it displays only active Cases with scheduled Activities. Indeed a confusing name.
If you close all Activities the Case is not shown.

Comment: Yes that sounds familiar. The actual code line is: $upcoming = CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCases(TRUE, $userID, 'upcoming', $context);
If you look on the fullsize case dashboard (not the dashlet) the wording makes it clearer. At the top right it says "All cases with upcoming activities".

Comment: OK, so we're making some progress, for which many thanks: the dashlet is effectively the same as the 'all cases' option on the Cases Dashboard, and we're assuming that it displays only active cases, i.e. not closed or deleted, and that it only displays cases where there is an "upcoming activity", aka a scheduled activity, and it has no filtering about the case client or coordinator or who the user is viewing the display.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance/confusion here, but is it fair to say that an upcoming or scheduled activity is one where it has a status that is scheduled, regardless of the date, or are there other criteria that define this activity. I recall some time ago reading somewhere that an upcoming activity was only included where the activity date was within 14 days of the current date - is that true?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I'm trying to understand why it seems to be near impossible to get a simple dashlet display listing all live cases. It seems clear now that the 'All Cases' dashlet, despite its name, does not provide this, and using the Case Summary report doesn't work either (see http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/differences-in-results-between-find-cases-and-a-case-report for the detail on that). Who would have guessed that it would be so difficult to create such a straightforward report/dashlet?

Comment: Yes 14 days AND activity status scheduled. Also case status not Closed. But Case Summary should give more or less what you want, it's just that at least 2 changes were made in 4.6 that seem to have broken it. Having said that, every org I've worked with has customized their login screen, and a flat listing of ALL never meets their actual business need, at least not for a homepage/dashboard/dashlet. For offline reporting yes, but again not in dashboard/dashlet form, there an excel file or export to other system is more useful. But your original question is right, the dashlet is not really ALL.

Comment: reference https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/4.6/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php, functions createCaseViewsQuery(), getCases(), and getCaseActivityQuery()